# If I use Multi Table Inheritance for a set of related classes can they have separate admins?

Tags: python, django

I need to choose between Multi Table Inheritance and ABC Inheritance and I am not sure if I can still have separate admins for each subclass. I need all the base class fields and all the fields from the subclass in each subclass admin screen.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I am still not even finished with the manual but I have a deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can have an admin screen for each of your models, and all the fields from base model would be present on child models.

[from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

> each model in the hierarchy is a model all by itself

Then, if you have:

**models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class VariationAService(Service):
    # fields

class VariationBService(Service):
    # more fields
```

You can do something like this:

**admin.py**

```
class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    [...]

class VariationAServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    [...]

class VariationBServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get all fields either way. The difference between the two is that with multi-table inheritance...

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

...you'll get both a `Place` object and `Restaurant` object, which can both be edited in the admin, but with abstract base classes...

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

...you'll only get a `Restaurant` object, which can be edited in the admin.